# How to get XPath paths one by one when you have multiple children nodes?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an XML of the form

```
<H1>h1</H1>
<H2>h2</H2>
<H3>
  <H4>h4-1</H4>
    <H5>
      <H6>h6-11</H6>
      <H7>h7-11</H7>
    </H5>
    <H5>
      <H6>h6-12</H6>
      <H7>h7-12</H7>
    </H5>
  </H4>
  <H4>h4-2</H4>
    <H5>
      <H6>h6-21</H6>
      <H7>h7-21</H7>
    </H5>
    <H5>
      <H6>h6-22</H6>
      <H7>h7-22</H7>
    </H5>
  </H4>
</H3>
```

I want to get all the paths till H7, i.e.,

```
h1,h2,h4-1,h6-11,h7-11
h1,h2,h4-1,h6-12,h7-12
h1,h2,h4-2,h6-21,h2-21
h1,h2,h4-2,h6-22,h7-22
```

How to do it using XPath in Java? I know how to do it when there is a single child node for every node but couldn't figure it out for multiple children nodes.

Comment: in java you can JSoup..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath can only help you identify one of the texts from your input file. For instance:

```
/H3/H4[2]/H5[1]/H6[2]/text()
```

would refer to the text "h7-21"

To iterate over things, you need a little more than XPath. XSLT for instance, or Java code.

Answer (score 0):

//H1 | //H2 | //H3 | //H4 | //H5 | //H6 | //H7
Try this one it will select all the tags